# Numbering in "book" not working as desired

Tags: table-of-contents

I have to write my report in "book style". Here is my preamble + text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% Load the VUB package.
% This has many options, please read the documentation at
% https://gitlab.com/rubdos/texlive-vub
\usepackage{vub}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[
  separate-uncertainty = true,
  multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[]{amssymb }
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[]{booktabs}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

% Some highly suggested packages, please read their manuals.
%\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage[natbib,style=apa]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{MY TITLE}
\pretitle{\flushleft{Graduation thesis submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of engineering sciences: Applied Sciences and Engineering: Applied Computer Science }}
\author{ME}
\date{2021-2022}
\promotors{MY PROF}
\faculty{faculty} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle%

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}  
blablabla

\newpage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}  
blabla
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}

blabla list

\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Tumor}

\section{Challenges}

\subsection{Heterogeneity}

\subsection{Non-contrast enhancing tumor}


\subsection{Manual Delineation}


\chapter{State of the art}

\section{Detection using technique A}
\section{Detection using technique B}
```

Even though I start with a \chapter{} command, my table of contents still numbers everything starting with 0.1, 0.2,0.3 etc...

For that reason I added the  `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` command, which removes the trailing zero but does not number my chapters in the TOC.

How do I get a TOC that looks like this:

```
TOC:

Abstract
Acknowledgements
List of abbreviations

1. Intro
 1.1 Section 1
 1.2 Section 2

2. Chapter2
 2.1 Section 3
 2.2 Section 4
```

instead of like this:

```
TOC:

Abstract
Acknowledgements 
Introduction 5
0.1 Tumor
0.2 Challenges
    0.2.1 Heterogeneity  
    0.2.2 Non-contrast enhancing tumor 
    0.2.3 Manual Delineation
State of the art: GBM delineation 
0.3 Detection using technique A
0.4 Detection using technique B
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If the sections only occur inside the numbered chapters, you shouldn't be getting "0.1", "0.2" at all. They should be "1.1", "1.2". (That's what I get when I try your code without `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`.) What behavior do you want? Do you want the sections just to be "1 Section 1" in the body text, but appear as "1.1 Section 1" in the ToC, so they are mismatched?

Comment: Weird, for me the sections appear as "0.1, 0.2" without ``` \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}```. I can post a more representative part of my text if that helps.

Comment: Yes, please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It would be helpful to use a single code block with code that can be compiled as is. You can remove everything unrelated to the problem.

Comment: you deleted the \mainmatter command. It is important ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This fixed it thank you! If you add it as an answer, I can accept it.